# Batch save pictures from multiple excel files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 10000 excel files, that in a specific cell of all of them there is a picture. I need a script to read all files and save the picture with the same name of the excel files in a folder.
Could you please help with that?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean "I need someone to write for me a script" or "I need someone to guide me how to write a script"?

Comment: The latter would be nice, but since I have little experience with VBscript the former would save time.

Comment: Well... I can only give you the guidance. Let's wait and see if there is someone around with more time....

Comment: Well, I'm ready if you have time... Completely ready.

Comment: I'll give you some guidelines in an answer (to be written and submitted in few minutes from now.

Answer (score 0):

This method is based on a number of assumptions:

1. All the files (10000) are located in a know folder,
2. All files are named according to a paradigm that can be reproduced programmatically (if not, you can get the list of files within the folder, store the list within an array, and loop through the array),
3. Pictures are always within the same worksheet or, if in more than one, the names of the worksheets can be reproduced programmatically,
4. The filenames to be used to save the pictures can match (at least as a seed) the one of the Excel the pictures are extracted,
5. You will manage to write some basic VBA.

Note that for the VBA you have at least two options:

1. Write it within an EXCEL that will only serve as the extraction engine, or
2. Write it as a stand-alone file and run it via DOS commands.

The VBA logic:

1. Create the outer loop that processes a single file,
2. Within the outer loop, generate the name of a file to be open,
3. Open the file using `Workbooks.Open` VBA function,
4. Select the worksheet and the cell containing the picture,
5. Use the `Workbook.SaveAs` to save the picture (you will need to specify the type of file to be used, e.g. `.bmp`).

As a simple and very efficient tool to get the code (at least) partially generated by Excel, you can RECORD a MACRO for each action and then stop recording. You will see the code generated (you will need to access the VBA mode). You can copy-paste the generated code into your development (you might need to do some simple adaptations though).

That's it.

Hope you manage. Good luck!!